# Allocation of an identity block into a larger matrix

Tags: julia

In matlab, assuming I want to build a matrix A containing an identity block, I may use

```
A = zeros(4,4);
A(1:2,1:2) = eye(2);
```

in julia, I know of the `UniformScaling / I` operator.
However I does not seem to be usable in the same fashion, and everything I read says that it supersedeed the `eye` operator.

What is the julianic way to do this ?

**EDIT:** I am currently using some `Diagonal(ones(...))` to actually create the diagonal block.

With respect to the first answer, it seems relatively comparable to the `Matrix(I...)` syntax (twice as slower max), but much better in terms of memory usage for large matrices (about a hundred times less).

See this code for test purposes

```
using LinearAlgebra
using BenchmarkTools


A = zeros(10,10)
@btime A[1:8,1:8] = Matrix(I,8,8)

B = zeros(10,10)
@btime B[1:8,1:8] = Diagonal(ones(8))

A == B

A = zeros(100,100)
@btime A[1:80,1:80] = Matrix(I,80,80)

B = zeros(100,100)
@btime B[1:80,1:80] = Diagonal(ones(80))

A == B

A = zeros(1000,1000)
@btime A[1:800,1:800] = Matrix(I,800,800)

B = zeros(1000,1000)
@btime B[1:800,1:800] = Diagonal(ones(800))

A == B
```

which returns

```
  155.858 ns (1 allocation: 160 bytes)
  176.879 ns (2 allocations: 160 bytes)
  6.680 μs (1 allocation: 6.44 KiB)
  10.799 μs (2 allocations: 752 bytes)
  617.099 μs (2 allocations: 625.14 KiB)
  1.007 ms (2 allocations: 6.39 KiB)
true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a generic way that hardly allocates at all:

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra, BenchmarkTools

julia> function func1(z, a, b)
           z[diagind(z)[a:b]] .= one(eltype(z))
           return z   end
func1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test = zeros(1_000, 1_000);

julia> @btime func1($test, 1, 2);
  68.680 ns (2 allocations: 80 bytes)

julia> @btime func1($test, 1, 500);
  441.919 ns (2 allocations: 80 bytes)

julia> @btime func1($test, 1, 1000);
  2.444 μs (2 allocations: 80 bytes)
```

Edited to add: in contrast to many other languages, the simplest and most efficient solution in Julia is often a loop:

```
julia> function func2(z, a, b)
           for i ∈ a:b
               z[i, i] = one(eltype(z))
           end
           return z
       end
func2 (generic function with 1 method)
julia> @btime func2($test, 1, 2);
  2.000 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime func2($test, 1, 500);
  265.337 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime func2($test, 1, 1000);
  2.200 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Comment: That's a nice one. It allocates very little indeed. And takes very little time (about 946 ns on my 1000x1000 example)

Comment: Your edit is a bit confusing, The for-loop allocates nothing, yet it requires more time than you previous solution. Why is that so ?

Comment: Sorry, that was confusing indeed as I benchmarked different operations (replacing a different number of diagonal items) - I've edited again to have the same number of substitutions for both functions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to Julia myself so feel free to correct me:

```
julia> z = zeros(Int, 4, 4)
4×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0

julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> z[2:3, 2:3] = Matrix{Int}(I, 2, 2)
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  0
 0  1

julia> z
4×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  0  0  0
 0  1  0  0
 0  0  1  0
 0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. Quite funnily, your solution is a bit faster that `Diagonal(ones(...))` yet uses much more memory...